# How to run selenium 3.x with chrome driver through terminal

Tags: selenium, testing, integration-testing, selenium-chromedriver

May be it's easy question but I can't find any info about that.

I used to run selenium 2.x as that way. I start server:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver -browserSideLog -debug -timeout 60
```

And then I run my tests. I use Dart so I do

```
pub run test test/selenium/custom_component_test.dart
```

But now i'm trying use selenium 3. I have downloaded it and substitute my old terminal call with new jar but seems I can do it. Selenium tells me it doesn't know such parameter "-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver". And in help I can't see parameters to specify parameter.

So, how to run selenium 3 with chrome driver?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

your options are out of order.  `-D...` is a java runtime variable. it needs to come before the `-jar` directive.

Change your command to

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -browserSideLog -debug -timeout 60
```

> I used to run selenium 2.x as that way.

Yes, we changed the source to use `JCommander` in 3.0 to parse options passed into the jar.  `-D` directives are now parsed as options you are trying to pass into the jar, just like `-debug` and `-timeout`.  For your command to be well formed, you really should be using `-D...` before the `-jar` directive.

Comment: i had same problem and now it works thx, I just wanted to know why -D should be used before -jar?