# How to run selenium with chrome node config

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

With 2.0 I have run Selenium grid with the following configuration setting in node configuration json:

```
{
  ...
  "configuration":[
    ...
    "dwebdriver.chrome.driver=...":""
  ]
}
```

Now I understand that the Configuration variable has been flattened, and have attempted to flattened the declaration, but Chrome doesn't start and displays an error in the node console.

I can successfully run chrome when I add the -D parameter (in the command line - thanks to [How to run selenium 3.x with chrome driver through terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262682/how-to-run-selenium-3-x-with-chrome-driver-through-terminal)) when I start the node, but would prefer to have it all contained in the node configuration file

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember being able to pass in JVM arguments [ `webdriver.chrome.driver` is basically a JVM argument ] via the JSON configuration file.

I also don't remember seeing any restructuring of the JSON configuration file that is either used to spawn the Hub or the node. They have always remained the same. ( See [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultHub.json) for sample hub config and [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultNodeWebDriver.json) for sample node config )

If you don't want to be specifying the location of the Chrome driver via the JVM arguments, I would suggest that you merely add the path to where the chromedriver.exe resides into your `PATH` variable as a one time activity per machine. After that you wouldn't be required to specify the location to where your chromedriver binary resides using the JVM argument.

Answer (score -1):

use this config file for node:
**notice the last two lines**

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "marionette": true,
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "internet explorer",
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "safari",
      "technologyPreview": false,
      "platform": "MAC",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 5,
  "port": -1,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://192.168.1.2:4444",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {},
  "webdriver.gecko.driver":"c:/drivers/geckodriver.exe",
  "webdriver.chrome.driver":"c:/drivers/chromedriver.exe"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work for me:
"..$java --version"
"openjdk 10.0.2 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4, mixed mode)"

Comment: mmm, I ran with JDK 8 and windows, but I thought it will work with u, as java is platform-independent and of course Selenium will run independently too. but what does it say?

Comment: The selenium logs didn't show any error and the scenario didn't execute complaining that the selenium server is not running.

Comment: was it really running?

Comment: Yes - I could see a connection was made to the node

Comment: Hi @Brian Barnes,  I tried to find a solution on my linux machine but I encountered this issue here:  https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/2091

Comment: I also tried to follow instructions here: https://seleniumhq.github.io/docs/grid.html   , of course I replaced the path to driver with one compatible with linux, in vain :( , for some reason it does not read the property "webdriver.chrome.driver" or "webdriver.gecko.driver" , I did not expect it would not work in linux as it does in windows. I dunno if this is a bug with Selenium Grid. if someone here has MAC OS. let's get feedback if really works with them

Comment: That github issue you've linked to is quite old (the issue was resolved back in 2016). The documentation appears to be what I followed for 2.x (and not 3.x) - the configuration variable was flattened for 3.x. I'm surprised that the documentation there hasn't been updated.

Comment: I thought it was the same problem, as I was unable to run the drivers in linux, using the same configurations it works well with Windows!!