# Which drivers come out the box with Selenium Standalone Server?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-server

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262682/how-to-run-selenium-3-x-with-chrome-driver-through-terminal) you can see how to make *Selenium Standalone Server* use the [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home). My question is, which drivers are include out the box in the *Selenium Standalone Server* jar?

Should I use the browsers drivers instead of the drivers included in the *Selenium Standalone Server* jar?

I know that with Firefox the Selenium Team [recommend](https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2016/10/13/selenium-3-0-out-now/) use the Firefox driver, but what about the others browsers?

Answer (score 1):

The post you have pointed out as `how to make Selenium Standalone Server use the chromedriver` is a demonstration of using **`Selenium Standalone Server in Grid configuration`** i.e. through setting up **`Selenium Grid Hub`** and **`Selenium Grid Node`**.

Selenium 3.x releases doesn't supports any of the drivers out the box in the Selenium Standalone Server jar.

The main reason behind **`Selenium Team`** recommending to use the **`geckodriver`** (Firefox) and **`Mozilla Firefox Browser`** because both **`geckodriver`** and **`Mozilla Firefox Browser`** follows the **`W3C`** Specifications.

Comment: also worth noting, Chrome is the same with Chromedriver.

Comment: @sircapsalot Thanks, I always saw you active with `Selenium` & `gecko` group :) I can't believe you would be mentioning `chrome` or `chromedriver` in your comment. Wait for my next video to expose vulnerability in Google Analytics :)

Comment: You quoted the doc: "language-specific client drivers" in a completely unrelated issue. One thing is the "language-specific client drivers" that you use to connect to Selenium Server and another completely different thing is the Browsers driver Selenium server use. So, my question is still unanserwerd.

Comment: @sircapsalot Could you state if the Selenium Server .jar include some driver out the box?

Comment: @DebanjanB Are you sure? I mean, you just wrap that sentence in two paragraphs that are still unrelated to the question even deal with my question content. I really appreciate you take time to reply and edit your answers after my comment, I don't pretend to be rude, I just want to be sure ;)

Comment: @gsi-frank no - no drivers come with the Selenium server post 3.0.  if you use Selenium < 3, then Firefox is included, but it's not "technically" the driver, since it was made by the Selenium team. Mozilla took ownership of their own driver called "Geckodriver" which is "not" included in our jars

Comment: @sircapsalot Thanks a lot!